# St_Difference between raster and vector using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I want to calculate the difference between a raster and vector layer,

I used this querie but it's so slow and I don't know if it's right or not.

I'm not using st_difference because it only support vector layers

`SELECT ST_Clip(a.raster,b.geom) 
FROM my_raster a, my_shape b
WHERE not ST_Intersects(a.raster, b.geom)`

I want to erase raster region wish is intersected with the vector layer

EDIT 1

Queries listed bellow work but they take a lot of time

To rasterise vector layer

```
create table rasterise_vector
select ST_AsRaster(st_transform(geom,4326), (select st_union(raster) from my_raster) , 2BUI') as raster
from shp
```

To calculate difference between rasters

```
create table diff_rasters as
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(st_union(a.raster), st_union(b.raster), 'rast1 - rast2', '32BF', 'FIRST', NULL, 'rast1', NULL)
from my_raster a, rasterise_vector b
```

Table size :

Raster size Rows (estimation) = 1046 tiles

Vector size Rows (estimation) = 9854 items

[image]

could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Hard to know without any metrics on table sizes, polygon complexity, etc. How big, how long. What does explain show?

Comment: How did you import your raster data into your database (100x100 tiles)? From th experiences I've made I think the union function could slow down the query noticable. Can you avoid it? What about tiling the new vector_raster?

Comment: exactly, I imported my ratser data with 100x100 tiles. I will test it by making tiles and give you my results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my idea:

1. Use [ST_AsRaster](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/RT_ST_AsRaster.html) to rasterize your vector layer (think about the resolution of the new raster layer)
2. Then use the [ST_MapAlgebra](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra_expr.html) function to create a new raster (new_raster values have raster values where vector_raster values are NULL or something like this.)

Comment: This is a very good idea, I tested it but the difference of rasters takes a lot of time, I added queries to my question

Comment: your answer is right, I made union out of queries and it's done